# Issues with UINavigationItem changing properties at runtime

Tags: ios, cocoa

i have a Navigation Bar, wich contains a Navigation Item, which contains 2 Bar Buttons, these are created in the Storyboard, and i wanted to change 1 of the buttons at runtime, now this works:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UINavigationItem *thisNavBar = [self myNavigationItem];
    thisNavBar.rightBarButtonItem = nil; // this works, it gets removed

    UIBarButtonItem *insertBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(insertSkemaItem:)];

    thisNavBar.rightBarButtonItem = insertBtn; // this also works, it sets the btn

}
```

Now, in my other method, which is called by another controller, it does not work

```
- (void)callChildChange { 

    ...

    // remove old btn
    UINavigationItem *thisNavBar = [self skemaNavigationItem];
    thisNavBar.rightBarButtonItem = nil; // does not work?
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the method, it runs just fine, but the nav btn item does not get removed ?

skemaNavigationItem is a Navigation item, declared in the .h file which links the navigation item i made via the storyboard.

Comment: If you log thisNavBar, does it come back non-nil?

Answer (score 0):

Your UI items need to be added to your code (by ctrl-dragging) in the header file (.h) so they can be publicly accessed from other classes/view controllers.

Presuming you've done this, hiding a UI item is best done by using

```
relevantClass.yourViewObject.hidden = YES;
```

or if you really need to delete it for good,

```
[relevantClass.yourViewObject.view removeFromSuperView];
```

**Edits**

Options for changing target method:

Declare `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL myButtonWasPressed;` and:

```
 - (IBAction) myButtonPressed
 {
     if (!self.myButtonWasPressed)
     {
         // This code will run the first time the button is pressed
         self.myButton.text = @"New Button Text";
         self.myButtonWasPressed = YES;
     } 
      else
          {
             // This code will run after the first time your button is pressed
             // You can even set your BOOL property back, and make it toggleable
          }

 }
```

or

```
- (IBAction) myButtonWasPressedFirstTime 
 {    
  // do what you need to when button is pressed then...

   self.myButton.text = @"New Button Text";    

   [self.myButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressedFirstTime) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   [self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonPressedAgain) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

 }

- (IBAction) myButtonWasPressedAgain
{
   // this code will run the subsequent times your button is pressed
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i do not want to hide it, i have the change the text and the action of the btn, and i have read that this cannot be done at run time, so i wanted to set it to nil, and then create a new btn

Comment: i think you are misunderstanding

Comment: I thought you wanted to remove this button from the view, and/or change the text and action of the button. Explain to me again what it is you want to happen.